# Find the line of intersection between 2 planes

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Q: Determine the line of intersection S of the planes 
$E: x + 2y − 2z = 13$ and $F: x − y + z = 3$

Ok so I let $Z=t$ and then used the simultaneous equations to solve for x and y, however I think I made a mistake. 
This is how I wrote the process:

First equation $x+2y-2t=13$

Second equation $x-y+t=3$
\begin{bmatrix}x+2y-2t=13\\ x-y+t=3\end{bmatrix}

$x+2y-2t=13$

$x+2y-2t-\left(2y-2t\right)=13-\left(2y-2t\right)$

$x=13-2y+2t$

Solving $13-2y+2t-y+t=3$

...gets me $y=-\frac{-3t-10}{3}$

Then I subsitute Y into X

$y=13-2(\frac{-3t-10}{3})+2t$

Solving that gives me $13-2\left(-\frac{-3t-10}{3}\right)+2t=-\frac{20}{3}+13$

$x=-\frac{20}{3}+13$

My x does not have a t at all, how can I compute a line equation without a t?

I got

$y=-\frac{-3t-10}{3}$
$x=-\frac{20}{3}+13$

I don't think it's right because of how complicated it looks, I also don't think I can make a intersection line equation without a t for my x. Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

If what I did was right then my line of intersection would be

$r$=$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$$=$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{20}{3}+13 \\
    -\frac{-3t-10}{3} \\
    t \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
$

Comment: The plane must be $(\frac{19}{3},\frac{5}{3},\frac{-5}{3})+(0,-3\lambda,-3\lambda)$. I don't think I understand your notation.

Comment: i'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You’ve lost a minus sign. You should have $x=13-20/3=19/3$ at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace equations E and F with any linear combination of themselves.
One is $E+3F$ which returns $x=7/3$.
Another is $E-F$ which gives $y-z=10/3$ .
Then $z=t,\; y=10/3+t, \; x=7/3$.
$ x$ does not have any $t$ , that is perfecty possible and licit, it means that the line has a constant $x$, i.e. that it lies on a plane orthogonal to x axis and intersecting it at $x=7/3$

Answer (score 1):

I let $z = 0$, and solved this on pen and paper.

[image]

Comment: why as 0 tho? So far we learned to use t, is it also ok to use 0?

Comment: That I don't that's how I was shown. I was never shown another way. Was using the cross product correct?

Answer (score 1):

It’s perfectly reasonable for $x$ to be constant. That just means that the line is parallel to the $y$-$z$ plane, but it also means that you’ll have to describe the line with two equations instead of lumping everything into one expression as you might be used to doing, i.e., as $$x=x_0 \\ {y-y_0\over b}={z-z_0\over c}.$$ (Actually, the symmetric form ${x-x_0\over a}={y-y_0\over b}={z-z_0\over c}$ is is itself really a shorthand for two separate equations.)